# Testing annotated actions with JUnit

Tags: testing, junit, struts2, annotations, action

Is there a way to test annotated actions with JUnit?

I have Struts 2 in my projects, and prefer to use annotations instead of declaring actions in struts.xml.

Still haven't find mechanism to test them without making custom struts.xml for testing.

Cannot make configuration consider annotations of action - it just don't know if action is attached to context-path.

Here is the code:

```java
public class MainMenuActionTestCase extends StrutsJUnit4TestCase<MainMenuJsonAction> {

    @Override
    protected String getConfigPath() {
        return "xxx/struts.xml";
    }

    @Test
    public void testUserNameErrorMessage() throws Exception {                   

        ActionProxy proxy = getActionProxy("/" + WebConstants.BUNDLE_NAME + "/mainMenuJson");

        MainMenuJsonAction accountAction = (MainMenuJsonAction) proxy.getAction();

        proxy.execute();

        List<MainMenuItem> lMenuItems = accountAction.getMenuItems();

        Assert.assertEquals("We have exactly three menu items", lMenuItems.size(), 3);

    }

}
```